# Firebase Sign Out Not Changing Views Working

Tags: swift, firebase

I have some firebase code with a listener set up in AppDelegate and a log out set elsewhere. It is not taking me to the login view controller when I click sign out.

Logout Code:

```
   @IBAction func logOutTapped(_ sender: Any) {
       try! Auth.auth().signOut()      
    }
```

App Delegate Code:

```
 let authListener = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
  
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

if user != nil
{
...//Some code
}
else
{
         print("Headed to login view controller.")
         let loginViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginViewController") as! LoginViewController
                self.window?.rootViewController = loginViewController
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }
```

I know the sign out code is calling the "else" in app delegate, because my logs are printing "Headed to login view controller" when I press logout. However, the login view controller is never displayed. It stays on the screen where the user clicks log out. When the app is stopped and started again, the login screen is displayed. The storyboard identifier is correctly set as loginViewController.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just change views within the view with the logout button? Once logged out, check if the user is nil and then perform a view change, that way you can also clear out and loaded views.

Comment: I'll give that a try. Thanks.